# Using dynamic name in v:bind inside v-for

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

So, basically, I have products array, and prices array, which has a product_id array inside (and inside that array I have the price and priceAfterDiscount data). The problem is that I am not able to pass this data using v-bind. (See :price="`prices.product_${product.id}.price`") This renders f.e. prices.product_8.price string instead of getting into array.

Thanks in advance. The code is below

```
<ProductCard v-for="product in products.data"
  :product="product"
  :key="product.id"
  :userСurrency="userСurrency"
  :user-currency-code="userCurrencyCode" 
  :price="`prices.product_${product.id}.price`" />
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm a bit confused? Is `prices` now an array or an object? I'll assume object because of it's usage. In that case you can use the indexing operator to pass a string like so:

```html
<ProductCard v-for="product in products.data"
  :product="product"
  :key="product.id"
  :userСurrency="userСurrency"
  :user-currency-code="userCurrencyCode" 
  :price="prices[`product_${product.id}`].price" />
```